# Autofield column is not showing in admin database

Tags: django, django-models

i have created a model Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_image', default='default.jpg')
  smallContent = models.TextField()
  content = models.TextField()
  data_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

but id field is not showing in admin panel. i did makemigrations and migrate and both are done successfully.
[image: image of admin panel]

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a readonly field I think you probably need to explicitly tell admin to show it.

I don't know if this will work but try in `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['display_id']

    def display_id(self, obj):
        return obj.id

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

Comment: Try this instead

Answer (score 0):

AutoField is generated after the model is saved. It is not provided in Admin Panel as it should not be editable.

If want to make id editable (not recommended) override it as a CharField instead of AutoField with primary_key=True.

Else if just want to show it in the panel (while editing a saved model), add it to the read_only list of your model admin.

Read about [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#autofield) here.